# Pass Array of Objects in v-model Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, v-model

Is there away to pass an entire array in v-model? I have a component render function that renders my form fields but I would like to use some of the data of the Question itself.

Currently I have 'question_uuid' and the value that I get from the model, but I would like something more like:

```
{
  "answers": {
    "d798a51c-1595-4252-956b-401ad441ea59": [
      { "uuid": "Within 10 meters", "more_params": "etc" }
    ]
  },
}
```

Currently getting this:

```
{
  "answers": {
    "d798a51c-1595-4252-956b-401ad441ea59": [
      "Within 10 meters"
    ]
  },
}
```

Entire available array:

```
"questions": [
        {
          "uuid": "d798a51c-1595-4252-956b-401ad441ea59",
          "question_name": "<p>Where is the hand wash facility located ?</p>",
          "field_type": "Checkbox",
          "label": "Proximity",
          "placeholder": null,
          "options": [
            {
              "uuid": "bc966635-a7b5-4c71-970a-ceee5b338c75",
              "option_name": "Within 10 meters",
            },
            {
              "uuid": "0541aef3-dddd-4089-9f42-717e755bad7d",
              "option_name": "Within 20 meters",
            },
            {
              "uuid": "e3aae357-005c-4d39-9894-8d7394e9276d",
              "option_name": "Within 30 meters",
            },
            {
              "uuid": "b7f706ef-4168-456c-a9e7-b9e4d91344e7",
              "option_name": "Within 40 meters",
            }
          ]
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve from the info posted. You have an "answers object" within in which you have an array of answers for each question? Would you like to bind the selected answers into the answers array? Your top example you have "uuid":"within 10 meters" - that doesn't look right from the available data...

Comment: I would like to achieve the top array, the middle array is what I currently get, the bottom array is the data I have available.

To put it simply, my v-model looks like this:

```
v-model="formData.answers[field.uuid]"
```

Hence the middle data set, how can I pass more params so it looks like the 1st data set in my question?

Comment: Clarify your question: what u trynna archieve? DO you asking for help with object convertion only? `v-model` is just Vue.js mechanism for `HTMLElement <-> JS variable` binding, so `v-model` refers to JS variable and can store anything.

Comment: `<component
              :is="field.field_type"
              v-for="(field, index) in section.questions"
              :key="index"
              v-model="formData.answers[field.uuid]"
              v-bind="field"
              @input="assignAnswer()"
              @change="assignAnswer()"
            />`
I have this component and the v-model needs to give me the dataset I mentioned in my question at the top

Comment: I currently don't see why there even have to be vue tags under the question since all that is described in the question is data transformation.

Comment: It is a dynamic component used to save for elements